# Using recorded mouse coordinates to draw on d3 canvas

Tags: python, events, d3.js

Is there a way to send "fake" events to a d3 canvas? 
I want to animate a bouncing ball based on pre-recorded trajectory. My code-base is in C++ and I am embedding python codes in my program to publish this on d3.

EDIT: Maybe mouseEvents is not the best place to look at. In future, I will have more than 1 ball rolling in the scene.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [PyQt4](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download) framework. It has a class [QMouseEvent](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qmouseevent.html), where you can specify position of the mouse.